# Computing the probability of waiting someone - Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have the following problem and I having trouble in finding it solution. I need a hint.

**The problem:**

Two people arranged to meet between 12:00 and 13:00. The arriving time of each one is i.i.d. and follows an uniform distribution. Given that someone has already arrived, find the probability that the waiting time is at least 30 minutes.

**My attempt**

I was trying to calculate that by doing that but it's wrong

P(X$\ge$0.5) = $\int_.5^\infty$ $\frac{1}{0.5} dx$

Can someone help me in solving that question?

Comment: “Given that someone has arrived” means what — that the current time is somewhere after the first arrival time? And is “the waiting time” the time from now until the second arrival (which could have already occurred)?

Answer (score 1):

Let  $\ X,Y \tilde{} \mathcal{U} (\lbrack 0,1\rbrack) $ be uniformly distributed on $\lbrack0,1\rbrack$. 0 for 12.00, 1 for 13.00. Now we want to compute the probability that $X-Y \geq 0.5$. For this we will need to find the distribution function of the $Z=X-Y$. We can do this by convolution. For further details please check, 
http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/StandarduniformStandardtriangular.pdf

Then we will get, $ f_Z(z) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{c} z+1 \quad -1\leq z\leq0  \\ 1-z \quad 0<z\leq1 \end{array} \right. $

Now you just have to compute, 
$ \mathbb{P}(Z\geq 0.5) = \int_{0.5}^1 1-z \ \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{8} $.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wrong, Please read http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath124/kmath124.htm.My email is frankchang91@gmail.com. Thank you

Comment: I apologize, You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive solution is to look at the unit square and consider the area

of the upper triangle of $|X - Y| > 1/2$.

Where $X$ is the arrival time of the one who has already arrived and $Y$ is the arrival time of the other person.

The area and probability is $1/8$.